# Multiple Log ins (Facebook and Spotify) with AppDelegate

Tags: ios, facebook, spotify, facebook-ios-sdk, appdelegate

I am making an app that uses both Spotify login and Facebook login. Both of their tutorials say to modify the application() in AppDelegate.swift file. My issue is that both log-ins calculate the return value (boolean) of the function separately, and I don't know how to combine them. My question is how to have both log ins work and use just the one return value from application(). For clarity, the desired for each log in is shown below.

The spotify SDK wants:

```
func application(...) -> Bool() {

    let auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()

    let authCallback = { (error : NSError?, session : SPTSession?) -> () in
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog("*** Auth Error \(error)")
            return
        }
        auth.session = session
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("sessionUpdated", object: self)
    }

    if auth.canHandleURL(url) {
        auth.handleAuthCallbackWithTriggeredAuthURL(url, callback: authCallback)
        return true
    }

    return false


}
```

And the facebook SDK wants:

```
func application(...) -> Bool {
     var wasHandled = FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication:sourceApplication)
     // any app-specific handling code here
     return wasHandled
}
```

Comment: Are you asking to write both code in openURL function?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution, but you can perhaps check if the URL was handled with one type and then try with the next type if it was not handled.
If both types cannot handle it then return `false`.
For example:

```
func application(...) -> Bool {

     var wasHandled = FBAppCall.handleOpenURL(url, sourceApplication:sourceApplication)

     // any app-specific handling code here
     if (!wasHandled) {
        // spotify code here...
        if auth.canHandleURL(url) {
            auth.handleAuthCallbackWithTriggeredAuthURL(url, callback: authCallback)
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    return wasHandled;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Spotify login

**YOUR_URL_SCHEME_IDENTIFIER_FOR_SPOTIFY** it it the same string mentioned in your ios project url schemes and also in spotify MyApplications Redirect URIs.

```
if ([[url absoluteString] hasPrefix:@"YOUR_URL_SCHEME_IDENTIFIER_FOR_SPOTIFY"]) { 

let auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()

let authCallback = { (error : NSError?, session : SPTSession?) -> () in
    if (error != nil) {
        NSLog("*** Auth Error \(error)")
        return
    }
    auth.session = session
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("sessionUpdated", object: self)
}

if auth.canHandleURL(url) {
    auth.handleAuthCallbackWithTriggeredAuthURL(url, callback: authCallback)
    return true
}

return false

}
```